# How to call java method from a javascript adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

In Javascript Adapter, I call a java function similar as below:

```
var reqTag = new com.awesome.project.bean.prop.Record;
reqTag.setServiceID("2039");
```

And the server return error in log showing that:

> [JavaPackage com.awesome.project.bean.prop.Record] is not a function, it is object. (javascriptAdapter.js#2676)

Server and java(dummy.jar) both are using 1.7.
This is the way we add the jar file to javascript adapter in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.awesome.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/dummy.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The MobileFirst Server 8.0 is using IBM JDK1.7.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? If yes, edit the question with the steps you've followed. Also provide your pom.xml. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/using-java-in-javascript-adapters/

Comment: We are using java 1.8 compile to 1.6. If the java method is static it work fine to get the object but fail in reqTag.setServiceID("2039");

Comment: You need to use the same Java version everywhere. Server and pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Typically in MobileFirst Foundation this error happens when the Java version that the server uses (per the definition in the system) is not the same as the Java version specified in the adapter's pom.xml file (which is used to compile the adapter), or vice versa.

I suggest to make sure that both are Java 1.8. See if this then works.

Comment: we do add some description in question for better understanding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to use Java 1.7 in both?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: It is not working if both using the same version. But we found out that if we move arround the java code inside javascritp to other adapter, it work. It is really adnormal... Can you explain why? We have many java code insing need to move arround to make mobilefirst happy:(

Comment: Of the sample works for you but your code doesn't then I cannot explain this... consider opening a PMR.